# How can I prevent the array of identifier tags for each student disappearing after re-fetching from API?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, tags, fetch

I have a list of students that will display onto the web browser depending on what you filter by name/tag. If those filter fields become empty, the page re-fetches all the students from an API and displays them.

The tags are stored in an array using `useState` for each Student object.

**Example Problem**: After adding a tag to a student, then somehow filtering the students, and then finally clearing the filter fields, all the students will be displayed again but WITHOUT their tags.

**Expected Outcome**: I need the student to keep their tags, at least for a current session on the website.

**Question**: How can I solve this? Should I use localStorage? or a Database such as MongoDB? or something else?

---

### Students.jsx

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import styles from "../views/Home.module.css";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
import AddIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Add';
import RemoveIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Remove';

const Students = ({student}) => {

  const [isShown, setIsShown] = useState(true);
  const [tags, setTags] = useState([]);

  const findAverageGrade = arr => {
    let sum = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      sum += parseInt(arr[i]);
    }
    return sum / arr.length;
  }

  const addTag = (event) => {
    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
      setTags([...tags, event.target.value])
      event.target.value = "";
    }    

  }

  return (
    <div key={student.email} className={styles.studentItem}>
      <img className={styles.studentImage} src={student.pic} />
      <div className={styles.studentInfoContainer}>
        <div className={styles.studentHeader}>
          <p className={styles.studentName}>{student.firstName.toUpperCase()} {student.lastName.toUpperCase()}</p>
          <button className={styles.expandBtn} onClick={() => {
            setIsShown(!isShown);
          }}>
            { isShown ? <AddIcon className={styles.expandBtn} /> : <RemoveIcon className={styles.expandBtn} /> }
          </button>
        </div>
        <ul className={styles.studentDetail}>
          <li>Email: {student.email}</li>
          <li>Company: {student.company}</li>
          <li>Skill: {student.skill}</li>
          <li>Average: {findAverageGrade(student.grades)}%</li>

          {!isShown ? <div>
            <table className={styles.gradesTable}>
              <tbody>
                {student.grades.map((grade) => (
                  <tr key={uuidv4()}>
                    <td>Test</td>
                    <td>{grade}%</td>
                  </tr>
                ))}
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
          : null }
          <div className={styles.tagOutput}>
            {tags.map(tag => (<p className={styles.tag}>{tag}</p>))}
          </div>
          <input id="tag-input" className={styles.addTagInput} type="text" placeholder="Add a tag" onKeyPress={(e) => addTag(e)}/>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Students;
```

---

### Home.jsx

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Students from '../components/Students';
import styles from "./Home.module.css";

const Home = () => {

  const [students, setStudents] = useState([]);
  const [nameFilteredStudents, setNameFilteredStudents] = useState([]);
  const [tagFilteredStudents, setTagFilteredStudents] = useState([]);

  const fetchStudents = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(`https://api.hatchways.io/assessment/students`);
    setStudents(response.data.students);
    setNameFilteredStudents(response.data.students);
    console.log(response.data.students);

  }

  const filterStudentName = async (searchName) => { 
    const searchNameFiltered = searchName.toLowerCase();
    console.log(searchNameFiltered);
    
    if (searchNameFiltered === "") {
      fetchStudents();
      return;
    }

    var newArray = await students.filter((student) => {
      return student.firstName.toLowerCase().includes(searchNameFiltered)
      || student.lastName.toLowerCase().includes(searchNameFiltered);
    })

    await setNameFilteredStudents(newArray);
  }

  const filterStudentTag = async (searchTag) => {
    const searchTagFiltered = searchTag.toLowerCase();
    console.log(searchTagFiltered)

    console.log(students.filter((student) => {
      console.log(student);
    }))

    // var newArray = await students.filter((student) => {
    //   return student.firstName.toLowerCase().includes(searchNameFiltered)
    //   || student.lastName.toLowerCase().includes(searchNameFiltered);
    // })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchStudents();

  }, [])

  return(
    <>
      <div>
        <input className={styles.searchInput} type="text" placeholder="Search by name" onChange={(event) => filterStudentName(event.target.value) }/>
        <input className={styles.searchInput} type="text" placeholder="Search by tag" onChange={(event) => filterStudentTag(event.target.value) }/>
        {nameFilteredStudents.map((student) => (
          <Students key={student.id} student={student} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  )
  
}

export default Home;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are passing the students prop to the child component, any time the students change the component will be re-rendered. Also since the filter is in the parent component, the child component will re-render because you are calling fetchStudents() in the filter function. You can toy with changing how you filter the students.